# WPF Dependency injection with NavigationService

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-injection

I'm looking for a better approach using DI in my WPF APP.
I'm using frame and NavigationService for navigation between tabs.
I'm using WPF with .NET framework 4.7.2, EF Core and for DI I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (DI from .NET Core).

Everything works well, but navigating between pages can get a little messy.
My MainWindow looks like this, loading the dependency. However I want to use IPersonOrchestration in UserProfile page and I have to pass it in parameter in order to use it there.

```
    private readonly IPersonOrchestration_personOrchestration;
    public MainWindow(IPersonOrchestration personOrchestration)
    {
        _personOrchestration = personOrchestration;
        
        InitializeComponent();

        _mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new UserProfile(personOrchestration));
    }
```

My UserProfile page, where I want to use that orchestration:

```
    private readonly IPersonOrchestration_personOrchestration;
    public UserProfile(IPersonOrchestration personOrchestration)
    {
        _personOrchestration = personOrchestration;
        
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And from UserProfile, there will be even more steps and with this implementation, I would have to pass orchestration from MainWindow in every paramater in each step.
Is there a way to initialize the dependency directly in UserProfile and not passing in parameter with navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a possible solution (although I'm not convinced this is the best way)
Changing MainWindow to this:

```
public readonly IPersonOrchestration _personOrchestration;
public static MainWindow AppWindow

public MainWindow(IPersonOrchestration personOrchestration)
{
    AppWindow = this;
    _personOrchestration = personOrchestration;
    
    InitializeComponent();

    _mainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new UserProfile());
}
```

The orchestration was made public and I Added a public reference to the Main window, since every other page is a "child" of MainWindow.
Then loading the orchestration in UserProfile like this:

```
private readonly IPersonOrchestration _personOrchestration;
public UserProfile()
{
    if (MainWindow.AppWindow?._personOrchestration!= null)
    _personOrchestration = MainWindow.AppWindow._personOrchestration;
    
    InitializeComponent();
}
```